# Qt - Serializing a tree structure (a lot of pointers)

Tags: c++, qt, serialization, qt4, tree

I have a tree structure with a lot of pointers, basically a node of the tree is like this

```
class Node
{
   Node *my_father;
   QVector<Node*> my_children;

  ... a lot of data
}
```

I need all these pointers to make my job easier while in RAM memory. But now I need to save all the tree structure on disk.. I was thinking about using QDataStream serialization (http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Qt_Object_Serialization).. but I don't think this is going to work with pointers.. right?

What would you suggest to save this big structure on disk and re-read it into RAM with pointers working?

Comment: then how am I supposed to retrieve exactly how the data is disposed in the tree?

Comment: there are many ways. here is one: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/09/29/an-interesting-tree-serialization-algorithm-from-dwarf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use the XML format? It's by design very easy to use with all structured data, with nested objects, like the tree structure you use. But you don't want to store pointers in it - just the actual data. (The data stored in your pointers, that describe tree structure will become a XML structure itself, so you don't need them).

Then you'll need to recreate the pointers during file read, when you allocate a new children for some node.

BTW sorry for making this answer and not comment but I can't write question comments yet ;].

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, there is no guarantee that pointers read from disk would ever be valid as such.  But you could still use them as 'integer IDs', as follows.  To write, save the pointers to disk along with the rest of the data.  In addition, for each class instance, save its own address to disk.  This will be that object's 'integer ID'.  To read,

1) Use the saved integer ID information to associate each object with its children and father.  Initially, you'll probably have to read all of your `Node`s into a single big list.

2) Then once the children, father are in memory write their *actual* addresses into `my_father` and `my_children` respectively.

Feels a bit hacky to me but I can't think of a more direct way to get at this.